# Not authorized when using EFS accesspoint on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-efs

I have EFS and also created EFS accesspoint.

I have mounted that accesspoint on lambda and also able to read/write file on EFS via lambda function.

The role I am using for console access has below permissions

```
elasticfilesystem:DescribeAccessPoints
Resource : "arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:eu-west-1:1278484xx:file-system/*"
```

In EFS console I am able to check accesspoint.
But in Lambda ---> configuration ---> File system --> It shows below

```
You are not authorized to perform elasticfilesystem:DescribeAccessPoints
```

I am not able to understand role has permission for DescribeAccessPoints and also able to view it from EFS console.But why not it works from lambda console.

Comment: Try using `"*"` for the resource.

Comment: @jellycsc Thanks Could be the reasion.Will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Your ARN looks wrong - it should start with "`arn:aws:...`" (not the other way around, as in your example).